# Android Auto Backup Conflict Resolution

Tags: android, android-backup-service, android-6.0-marshmallow

Android M introduced Auto Backup for Apps:
https://developer.android.com/preview/backup/index.html

How does this service handle conflict resolution?

Example: I have 2 Android devices linked to the same Google Play account, running the same app; and that app has different data on it between the two devices. When Android backs up the data how does Google determine which to keep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: both are kept

Backup data for an app is associated with one specific device. If you factory reset that device it is henceforth considered a new device.

What this means is that if you have two Android devices on the same Google account they will both have duplicated backup sets, that are independent of each other. 
The next time you go through the Setup-Wizard on a new device and add your Google account, you will have the option to restore from either of the two devices.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that the auto-backup binds the backup to a particular device? I haven't found it yet.

Comment: But what would the alternative be?
http://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html
Describes that backup is *not* sync, which implies it's tied to the lifecycle of a device, no?

Comment: I don't doubt that the solution you describe is most likely the way it works. It makes the most sense. However I haven't seen them mentioning that conflict and its resolution in the docs so I was curious whether I missed something or where you have your knowledge from.

Comment: I work on Android Backup/Restore, which is why I was asking where the confusion came from - I could try to get it added to the public docs but I am not sure where it would fit.

Comment: Ha! Cool. Yes, that would be nice. :)